# Assign an operation in JComboBox once its clicked

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am having trouble with **jComboBox**. what I want to happen is once i clicked the word "half payment" on it. The value from the `jLabel or in`TextBox will be divide from half or 2 rather on that photo shows the value "235840" once I clicked the "half payment" in jcombobox the result will be 117920". i have an error says:`incompatible types: void cannot be converted to string. Whats wrong with this?":(

here's my code:

```
private void jComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        DefaultListCellRenderer dlcr = new DefaultListCellRenderer(); 
        dlcr.setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultListCellRenderer.CENTER); 
        jComboBox.setRenderer(dlcr); 

        String x = (String)jComboBox.setSelectedItem("HALF PAYMENT");
        int value = 2;
        String r = Integer.toString(value);

        int a = Integer.parseInt(x);
        String y = ttlpayment.getText(); //ttlpayment is jlabel
        int b = Integer.parseInt(y);

        int tot = a / 2;
        String z = Integer.toString(tot);
        ttlpayment.setText(z); //ttlpayment is jlabel


    }
```

[Here is my example form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUMjI.png)

[image]

Comment: Please, show more code. In this code, have error: `jhalf.setSelectedItem("HALF PAYMENT");` not return anyting

Comment: hey @mr mcwolf I already have a function in which where the value from the label cames from. And in that part in combo box i dont know what happen :(

Answer (score 2):

This makes no sense:

```
String x = (String)jhalf.setSelectedItem("HALF PAYMENT");
```

`setSelectedItem(...)` is a **setter** method, not a **getter** method, and like most setter methods it sets the state of the object that it is called on, here the jhalf JComboBox, but returns void or *nothing*, and so you can't get a String from it. Not sure what you want `x` to be, and you will want to improve your question and clarify your issues and your code to get a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple demo how to work with JComboBox

```
public class DemoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String values[] = {
            "--- SELECT MODE OF PAYMENT ---",
            "FULL PAYMENT",
            "HALF PAYMENT"
        };

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("PHP");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField("235840.00");

        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(values);
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Double value;
                try {
                    value = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                    value = 0.0;
                }

                JComboBox<String> comboBox = (JComboBox<String>)e.getSource();
                switch(comboBox.getSelectedIndex()) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Payment: " + value);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Payment: " + value / 2.0);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(textField);
        frame.add(comboBox);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```